# why python helium option value fails with CSS selector

Tags: python, css, selenium, helium

I have the following html fragment.

```
<select id="priority1" class="selectPriority form-control">
    <option value="/ABCD" selected="selected">
        10 Parameter x100
    </option>
    <option value="DEF">
        10 Parameter x150
    </option>
</select>
```

Using the below CSS selector to select all the option tag fails

```
find_all(S("#priority1 > option"))
```

However this works

```
[                                                              
    options.web_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")    
    for options in find_all(S("#priority1"))                   
]
```

I am unable to understand this weird behavior can anyone please explain as whats going on

Comment: Can you try this instead `find_all(S("#priority1 option"))` ? Also  I see one trailing space here `find_all(S("#priority1 > option "))`

Comment: Thanks i tried removing the space and also with your suggestion but it returns an empty array

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```
Selector          Example   Example description
--------          -------   -------------------
element element   div p     Selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements
element>element   div > p   Selects all <p> elements where the parent is a <div> element
```

So *`find_all(S("#priority1 > option"))`* would select all the `<option>` elements where the parent element's **`id`** attribute value is `#priority1`. Hence instead of selecting all the `<option>` elements, it would select only one.

---

### Solution

To select all the `<option>` tags you need to use:

```
find_all(S("#priority1 option"))
```

Comment: My Apologies i still didn't quite get this.When i do find_all(S("#priority1 > option")) i get an empty array/List as a result.And if i do find_all(S("#priority1) i do get [<select id="priority1" class="selectPriority form-control">...</select>]

Comment: @asfandhikmat Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking a look at this and i tried your latest suggestion somehow I am still getting the same response an empty list []